# How to pass class (clickable-row) for each row using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, datatable

First of all, i use the plugin Datatables. I'm an absolute noob when it comes to programming and probably didn't understand some basics. hopefully you can help.

Problem:
I am trying to pass data to my table using an array and json_encode.  This also works so far.Also the two hrefs with their icons are displayed in each row and work.  But I am not able to click on the rows, so my modal is opened.I have already found out that this is because the class clickable-row is not transmitted. So my question is: How can I use ajax and Datatable plugin to get each row to be assigned to a clickable-row class.  Other solutions are also welcome.

Here is my current code.

view.php

```
<table id="tabelle1"  style="width:100%" class="table text-center table-hover border ">
<thead class="thead-light">
    

<th class="no-sort":>&nbsp;Aktion</th>
<th>Leiterkartenname</th>
<th>Auftraggeber</th>
    


</thead>

!!!here the body of handling.php should be displayed!!!

</tr>
</tbody>
</table>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 

var table = $('#tabelle1').DataTable({


  "processing": true,

                    "ajax":{
                        url :"handling.php",
                        type: "post",

                        error: function(){ 
                            $(".tabelle1-error").html("");
                            $("#tabelle1").append('<tbody class="tabelle1-error"><tr><th colspan="3">No data found in the server</th></tr></tbody>');
                            $("#tabelle1_processing").css("display","none");
                            
                        }
                    },

  "stateSave": true, "scrollX": true,  "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]] , "info": false, "order":[],

  "initComplete": function(){
  $('#tabelle1').show()
  table = $(tabelle1).dataTable();
  table.fnDraw(false);
  }

        
});
});
</script>
```

and my handling.php

```
$result = !!!result from query!!!;

while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
        
$nestedData=array();

$nestedData[] = "
    
<tbody>
<tr class='clickable-row view_data' id='$row[ID];'>

<a href=\"PlatinenKnoepfeIndex\bearbeiten1index.php?ID={$row['ID']}&Leiterkartenname={$row['Leiterkartenname']}&Anzahl={$row["Anzahl"]}\" role='button'  class='liniebug' >
<i class='fa fa-edit' id='iconklasse'></i>  
 
<a href=\"PlatinenKnoepfeIndex\loeschenindex1.php?ID={$row['ID']}\" role='button' class='liniebug confirmation1'>
<i class='fa fa-trash-alt' id='iconklasse'></i>
    
";
    

$nestedData[] = $row["Leiterkartenname"];
$nestedData[] = $row["Auftraggeber"];

$data[] = $nestedData;
}

$json_data = array("data" => $data);

echo json_encode($json_data);
```

[this is how the result looks like (for illustration)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtYSv.png)

Comment: The only difference between href and class lines looks like double quotes and single quotes usage. I think you can try to put double counts around class names. As far as I can see, tbody opening tag should be on view.php since you're adding a new opening tag each step in the loop.

Comment: _“I have already found out that this is because the class clickable-row is not transmitted.”_ - no, that is likely not the problem. Much more likely, it is in how you bind your click handler to those elements in the first place. If you do this the ”normal” way, then it applies only to elements present in the DOM at that point - so whatever you load later per AJAX, simply isn’t affected. The keyword to work around that problem, is _event delegation_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the problem by passing the id instead of the html code. like this:

```
$nestedData[] = $row["ID"];
```

if a row is clicked now, it reads the id from the first column . like this:

```
var Id = table.api().row($(this).closest('tr')).data()[0];
```

Then the id is passed on to my handling.php using ajax.

I also initialized the buttons with the Datatable plugin, which also reads the id from the first column when it is clicked.